# Invalid argument for foreach

Tags: php

there is no issue with this query, as when I use `print_r` it prints out three different arrays, Im just wondering what Im missing here to get this `foreach` working, as at the moment Im getting an error...

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\admin\account_list.php on line 11

```
<?php 

$account_list = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
$query = $connect->query($account_list);
while  ($final_result = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($final_result);
// echo '</pre>';
}
echo '<table><tbody>';
foreach ($final_result as $result) {
echo '<tr><td>'.$result['id'].'</td>
<td>'.$result['firstname'].'</td>
<td>'.$result['lastname'].'</td>
<td>'.$result['email'].'</td>
<td>'.$result['address'].'</td>';
}
echo '</body></table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is, you're not calling `foreach` until after the query has completed, at which time `$final_result` is `FALSE`.  `foreach (false as $result)` is, indeed, invalid.

You'll want to combine the two loops:

```
$account_list = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
$query = $connect->query($account_list);

echo '<table><tbody>';

$final_result = false;

while  ($result = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  // echo '<pre>';
  // print_r($final_result);
  // echo '</pre>';

  $final_result = $result;

  echo '<tr><td>'.$result['id'].'</td>
  <td>'.$result['firstname'].'</td>
  <td>'.$result['lastname'].'</td>
  <td>'.$result['email'].'</td>
  <td>'.$result['address'].'</td>';
}

echo '</body></table>';
```

Comment: `$result=$final_result;` missing inside the loop. +1 for a nice answer

Answer (score 0):

`$final_result` is not an array, but an element of the array, instead of while just write-

```
$final_result = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: `fetch_array` return one row, so for this answer to be correct, you need to use `fetch_all` instead.